# How to set confidential mode with one week expiry in gmail powershell script?

Tags: powershell, email, gmail, powershell-2.0, gmail-api

I am using a PowerShell script to send emails. I need help that how can I set confidential mode with one-week expiry so that after one week the email should be deleted from the receiver's inbox.

Below is the code which is being used currently by me. please help to modify the same.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET GmailAccount=%~1
SET GmailPassword=%~2
SET Attachment=%~3
setlocal
set "date=%date%"

CALL :PowerShell
CD /D "%PowerShellDir%"
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PSScript%' 'abc@gmail.com' 'password' 'abcfilename.xlsx'"
EXIT

:PowerShell
SET PowerShellDir=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
SET PSScript=%temp%\~tmpSendeMail.ps1
IF EXIST "%PSScript%" DEL /Q /F "%PSScript%"

ECHO $Username      = $args[0]>> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $EmailPassword = $args[1]>> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $Attachment    = $args[2]>> "%PSScript%"
ECHO                          >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $Username    = $Username                 >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $EmailTo     = "receipient@gmail.com" >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $EmailFrom   = "abc@gmail.com" >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $Subject     = "Sybject Name - %date%"           >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $Body        = "Dear User Text body"              >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPServer  = "smtp.gmail.com"          >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body) >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $Attachment  = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($Attachment)                            >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($Attachment)                                                    >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)                               >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true                                                                >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $EmailPassword) >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)                                                               >> "%PSScript%"
GOTO :EOF
PAUSE
```

Comment: Confidential mode is an account setitng, not an email setting. All that happens is that when your account sends an email wioth confidential mode enabled, Google sends a link to the email on ther servers insetad of the actual email

Comment: But even after enabling it for my account. still, in every email, I have to enable confidential mode. if it is an account-level setting then it should be enabled for all emails I am composing.

Comment: It's a gmail-specific feature, nothing to do with the standard email protocol. You'd have to use their API.

Comment: can you guide me with some info on that API?

Comment: No, you'd ahve to go ask a specific question in an appropriate place for that. Probably a gmail devleoper forum.